# function to set text as bold in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit

Hi I am trying to make a function in Qt that sets the font of a QTextEdit to bold:

```
void TextEditor::setBold(){
    if (editor->fontWeight() == 75)
        editor->setFont(QFont::setBold(false));
    else
        editor->setFont(QFont::setBold(true));

}
```

I am getting error: cannot call member function 'void QFont::setBold(bool)' without object

not sure how to assign an object here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `setBold` is not a `static` method for using it you have to make an object.

```
void TextEditor::setBold(){
  QFont font(editor->font());

  if (editor->fontWeight() == 75)
      font.setBold(false);
  else
      font.setBold(true);

   editor->setFont(font);
}
```